# How to get HTML links to different pages on a website to update the URL instead of adding to it

Tags: html

If I click on About, I'm taken to .com/about then from there if I click on contact, I'm taken to .com/about/contact. How can I get this to change from .com/about to .com/contact?

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
```

Comment: You need to make the links relative to your root directory. Something more like `href="/../about"`. Google "relative html links"...

Answer (score 2):

Put a slash in your URL:

```
<a href="/contact">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Use Below piece of code
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
       </body>
       </html>
```